# Is there a way to run a Java program from JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps

For a school culminating, I have been given data to work with and create a visualization.  I had started by creating a Java project in Netbeans to read the file and create objects out of the data.  Now, I have decided to visualize the data using the Google Maps API which requires JavaScript and I want to avoid having to re-code everything using JavaScript.  So... is there a way for my webpage (in JavaScript) to run my Java program (which will give me objects) and return an array full of these objects?  Also, if it changes anything, I want to run the webpage without a server from my computer directory.

Thanks,
     Josh

Comment: You could make your java program output a json file of your data and have that local page use that to populate your maps. Also you can make an applet that talks to javascript, Heres a link to get started http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this directly. I recommend making your Java program into a web service and returning the results in JSON.

Comment: Forgive me for being such a noob but how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Use a library such as http://www.json.org/java/ (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java)